# MongoDB Agent Fatal log is growing Size Daily

Tags: cloud, mongodb, gcp

I have Deployed MongoDB Replica Set Cluster on the Cloud Manager and the MongoDB Agents running the Remote Servers.

MongoDB Version - 4.4.28 - ent
MongoDB Agent version - 13.13.0.8738

So at one point of time, my boot disk storage is filled and unable to SSH the Machines.

While checking the console logs found no space left on device. Then we increased the boot disk and able to SSH into the machine.

Then after investigating, the space is going the logs folder and in that folder there's only one log file is taking more.

here it's - **-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongodb mongodb 82G Mar 12 07:51 /var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/automation-agent-fatal.log**

can anyone help n why only that log file is growing and also how to avoid the log file size growing